# Android:Continuous Location update

Tags: android, location, android-location

I am working on one application in which I need to track user's location. So, I tried **Fused Location Api (GoogleApiClient)** and **LocationListener** and it gaves me location on regular interval.

But my problem is when my device is in steady state, still it gave me different Location on **onLocationChanged(Location location)**

Can anybody guide me how to resolve above issue!

Source code:

http://pastebin.com/Pu7cNF8h

Comment: In Location Request add `mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(100);` **100**  represent meters - [Refer](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest). Then Location Provider didn't give any value if you are in steady state.It will give **Latitude** and **Longitude** for every **100** meters.

Comment: @Yugesh: Thank you for prompt reply.. I will try you suggestion and will let you know..

Comment: You are probably getting the drifting locations due to the phone being in an area that degrades GPS (office buildings, malls, etc), which probably forces Fused Location Api to revert back to network locations (which are very inaccurate).  I would suggest you add in activity recognition at timed intervals, and if they are STILL for a period of time, setup a geofence around their area, and turn off Fused Location Api.  This will probably save power in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase **Smallest Displacement** so that it will not change location for little movement.

```
mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(100);
```

Displacement measured in meters. So you need to move at least 100 meters from the location of the initial location update to have a new location update.